# What are the most important considers before creating index in mySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, amazon-rds

I am using several RDS instances most of them r4.xlarge I have a lot of tables some of them with retentions and some not.

I am trying write a  "runbook" policy about checks before indexing.

1. When is  it dangerous creating an index maybe above num of rows? From my experience above few millions is dangerous. Maybe there is better way than number of rows.
2. Tables who are updating in high  frequency ? `select count(*) updatedAt from <tableName> where updatedAt >  (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 hour)`
3. Size of data ? I can know it by `SELECT TABLE_NAME AS "Table",TABLE_SCHEMA, ROUND((DATA_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024) AS "Size (MB)" FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'xxxxx' Group by TABLE_SCHEMA DESC;`

*** Most of my instances are using around 40-60 average cpu and running on r5.4xlarge machines

Comment: What do you mean by "dangerous?"

Comment: You might like to read my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), or the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU).

Comment: A.By dangerous I mean, avoiding failOver from the writer to reader (which happen if CPU is raising to 100).
B. I will watch for sure :)

Comment: When I create indexes, I use [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html). This tool allows you to create indexes or do other ALTER TABLE operations and continue to use the table for read and write. The tool monitors a couple of indicators of high load, and automatically slows itself down. I've watched indexes added to tables with a billion rows on database servers I was supporting. It can take days to add an index at that scale, but there was no downtime.